# Wordpress multi-site for subdomains and different domains with one database?

Tags: multisite, multi-language, subdomains, domain

I'm working onf a wordpress that has lots of posts. They're not in any language (they are either just images or addresses) but I want to make my site available in other languages (for wordpress texts) using subdomains or completly different domains.
For example:
My site is in Spanish and this is its URL:

```
example.es
```

Now I want to make it available in Basque with the following URL:

```
eu.example.es
```

But I also want to make it international and for those cases I want to use a different domain, for example, in french:

```
example-en-francaise.fr
```

Each of them would be in a different language but they would all be sharing the same database. What would be the best option for this? Would it be possible to only show the posts that are in the language of the domain (Spanish for .es, French for .fr, etc.)?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should also show how you're adding the language specific data to your site: Post Meta Data? Additional Posts + Custom Field? etc...

Comment: Most of the data (everything but the comments) is neutral to the language (streets don't change their names depending on the language). My main problem with the language lies with the comments.